# apostrophe in xsl:format-number

Tags: xslt, xpath, format

I parse an xml with my xslt and get the result as a xml.

i need to format numbers with apostrophe as delimiter for a tousand, million, etc...

eg: 1234567 = 1'234'567

now the problem is how do i get these apostrophes in there?

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(/path/to/number, '###'###'###'###')" />
```

this doesn't work because the apostrophe itself is already delimiting the start of the format.

is there a simple solution to that (maybe escaping the apostrophe like in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research we came up with this solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:decimal-format name='ch' grouping-separator="'" />
     <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select='format-number(/the/path/of/the/number, "###&apos;###&apos;###", "ch")'/>
     ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on whether you are using 1.0 or 2.0.

In 2.0, you can escape the string delimiter by doubling it (for example 'it''s dark'), and you can escape the attribute delimiter by using an XML entity such as `&quot;`. So you could write:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(/path/to/number, '###''###''###''###')" />
```

In 1.0, you can escape the attribute delimiter by using an XML entity, but there is no way of escaping the string delimiter. So you could switch your delimiters and use

```
<xsl:value-of select='format-number(/path/to/number, "###&apos;###&apos;###&apos;###")' />
```

The other way - probably easier - is to put the string in a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="picture">###'###'###'###</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(/path/to/number, $picture)" />
```

Comment: thanks but nothing worked... but i post the solution we found

Comment: It's very unconstructive to say "nothing worked", implying that none of my solutions worked. If they didn't work then either you implemented them incorrectly, or you are using a buggy processor. People reading this will want to know which. Say what you did and what error you got.

Comment: OK, i retried all your solutions on this site: http://xslttest.appspot.com/. Still no solutions works. I get the error "Error: format-number picture: Passive character must not appear between active characters in a sub-picture.".

Comment: That suggests you didn't have an xsl:decimal-format declaration. Sorry I forgot to mention that - I sort of assumed you would already have worked that part out.